# Incorrect access detected, this server may be accessed only through "http://localhost/moodle" address, sorry. Please notify server administrator.

Tags: networking, moodle

[image]

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101286/cannot-access-moodle-from-another-computer) question then after i cannot access from localhost.
is there any solution so that i can use both ways

Comment: looking at your print screen i think you are using ubuntu? please post your httpd.conf settings for this site presuming you are using apache2

Comment: i am not able to find httpd.conf can you just give where it should be located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the answer described in the other section, you can still access it FROM the local host (same machine), but you have to you the syntax:

```
 http://192.168.1.50/moodle/
```

instead of

```
 http://localhost/moodle/
```

Comment: i tried both but still it's not working.also added  allowed ip list then after my moodle crash suddenly

Comment: What error does it show when it crashes ? Could you please elaborate what exactly do you mean by it crashes ?

Comment: List? It shouldn't be a list, it is what the moodle wwwroot is (what you should be putting into the URL bar of your browser to bring it up). It should look like `$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://192.168.1.50'; `

Comment: my problem is we have installed Firewall in Our Company so each Every Time my ip has been change.Its Our project study Part because our company is going to make new LMS and we are taking functionality of moodle. My Machine Is Use as moodle Server

Comment: If there is a machine name that will resolve locally on the network, that would solve the problem if your address changes, it would just  be `$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://machinename';`

Comment: Its Works Digital Chris !!! i can access using machine name and its work over network as well.